# Chrome extension - select text in arbitrary box

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome extension that lets me drag out a box and ONLY select the text in that box.  Chrome by default will select all text from the start to the end of my dragged box, including text outside the box.

Is there any way to do that? I'm googling and I'm not sure it's technically possible?

Comment: That's an interesting task. A brute force approach would be to calculate each character's getBoundingClientRect using Range API and then do the basic math stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I am scared that's going to be my option, actually tracking the size of each character.  But, I don't want to just clip them, I want to highlight them visibly.

Comment: Ah. Well, multiple separate ranges in Selection API are supported only in Firefox AFAIK so you'd have to imitate the highlight using CSS.

Comment: Ugly.... :)  That's a decent idea, but sounds like a lot of work.....